# Cannot uninstall Greenshot on Windows 10

Tags: uninstall, greenshot

In preferences the "launch at startup" is checked and greyed out.

I want to uninstall Greenshot but it tells me it is on and therefore won't let me uninstall it.

Greenshot has overtaken my other program, Gadwin, and I want to revert to Gadwin but can't get rid of Greenshot.

I even tried a system restore to get rid of it, no luck.

Comment: Sounds like you will want to manually disable the services associated with Greenshot, only then should you attempt to uninstall Greenshot, if that still does not help you need to provide specific error messages.

Comment: Greenshot is compatible with the current Windows 10 release. This problem has nothing to do with incompatibility. It says clearly that it's running in the background in the error message and I can reproduce the same error on my PC when the Greenshot icon is present in the system tray.

Comment: SUCCESS! I moved the .exe file elsewhere, restarted Windows and naturally it couldn't find it and I was able to uninstall.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Side-note: Greenshot does not "take over" any other software. Maybe both tools try to register for the same hotkeys (e.g. <kbd>Print<kbd>). In theory, you could run both in parallel by changing e.g. Greenshot's hotkeys to something else.

Answer (score 3):

This error is telling you that the Greenshot process is still running in the background:

[image]

You can either close Greenshot by right clicking on its icon in the system tray, then choosing `Exit`:

[image]

... or by ending its task from the Task Manager:

[image]

The application will then uninstall normally once its process is no longer running in the background:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Mr Ethernet's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1508697/247669) is correct. You need to exit Greenshot in order to uninstall it.

In response to 'In preferences the "launch at startup" is checked and greyed out.': This happens if you installed Greenshot with admin permissions, but run it as a "normal" user. Exiting Greenshot and re-starting it as administrator should enable the checkbox.